# Why does "php artisan migrate" command resulted in "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused" error?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**TL;DR**: Turns out this was due to MySQL not installed on my local machine. Installing, configuring, and starting the MySQL server fixed it.

In the database migrations section, on [Laravel Bootcamp's Build Chirper with Inertia](https://bootcamp.laravel.com/inertia/installation), after I entered the command:

`$ php artisan migrate`

it threw an error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

I searched within Stack Overflow for previous instances of similar issue such as:

- [SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused within Laravel homestead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35394230/sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-refused-within-laravel-homestead)
- [Laravel SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41225720/laravel-sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-refused)
- [Database Laravel php artisan migrate connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43804784/database-laravel-php-artisan-migrate-connection-refused)
- [Laravel; "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28385251/laravel-sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-refused)

From these questions, all of the highest scored answers suggested to edit the `DB_HOST` in the `.env` file from `127.0.0.1` to `localhost`.

However, after I edited my `.env` file and ran the command:

`$ php artisan migrate`

it threw a different error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

Here's a snippet of my `.env` file that might be related to Laravel database migrations:

```
...

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

...
```

Plus, some additional info:

- Laravel: **10.29.0**
- PHP: **8.1.2**
- Composer: **2.6.5**
- Ubuntu: **22.04.3**

Thus, why does "php artisan migrate" command resulted in "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused" error? And what should I do to resolve this problem?

**Update**:

Troubleshooting process:

- Run `$ mysql -V` to check if MySQL is installed.
- Run `$ sudo apt install mysql-server` to install MySQL.
- Run `$ sudo mysql` to configure MySQL.
- Run `$ sudo systemctl start mysql.service` to start MySQL server.
- Run `$ systemctl status mysql.service` to check if MySQL server is started.
- Insert `''` between the password for `DB_PASSWORD` in the `.env` file.
- Run `$ php artisan migrate` to initiate database migration.

Recommendations when following [Laravel Bootcamp's Build Chirper with Inertia (Installation)](https://bootcamp.laravel.com/inertia/installation):

- Even though not explicitly stated, install MySQL alongside the required PHP and Composer on your local machine.
- After installing MySQL and configuring it, insert `''` between your password for `DB_PASSWORD` in the `.env` file.
- Before initiating the database migration, make sure your MySQL server is started.

Comment: Changing the host just because you read it in another answer won't help. Your original host seemed to be working, but the credentials used to connect seem to be wrong. Reading the error message is usually the best first step. Before you try to google it, just read it and try to understand what the error message says.

Comment: The error message indicates that there's something wrong with the MySQL connection. Then, I'm curious if MySQL is even installed on my local machine by checking it via `$ mysql -V` that resulted in `command not found`. The tutorial prerequisites is installing only PHP and Composer, so I falsely assumed that MySQL is bundled with those software. Which in turn, made me also falsely assumed that when I entered `$ php artisan serve`, the MySQL server was also automatically ran. So, it appears that my problem is due to MySQL not installed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it seems that your machine (operation system) doesn't have a database management system. you need to install a DBMS on your machine so that you can use it.
you can install mysql or postgresql or any other DBMS depends on your need.

ubuntu docs: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/databases-mysql (or install LAMP package: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/lamp-applications )

similar tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-ubuntu-18-04#step-2-installing-mysql

Comment: I checked `$ mysql -V` and it resulted in `command not found`. So, it seems that MySQL is not installed in my local machine. The tutorial prerequisite is installing only PHP and Composer. That's why I thought that MySQL is bundled with those two software, but it looks like I need to install MySQL separately.

Comment: After I installed and configured MySQL, I then ran `$ php artisan migrate` but it resulted in `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'` error message. I will troubleshoot this problem first before I can decide whether to accept your answer or not.

Comment: @GulfaniPutra that error (`access denied`) happens when your password is not correct, if you don't remember the password when you were installing the database, change your database's password https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-reset-your-mysql-or-mariadb-root-password-on-ubuntu-20-04 and then edit your project .env file to set the password.

Comment: After I used `''` between my password for `DB_PASSWORD=` in the `.env` file, the initial database migration now works.

Answer (score -1):

The "Connection refused" happens when Laravel could not connect to a database. This means that the credentials in the `.env` file are not correct. For example, the password or port may be wrong. Maybe you even forgot to start the MySQL server?

Since you're just getting started, maybe it would be simpler to use SQLite as a development database instead of MySQL? Assuming you have all the needed extensions, simply swap out all the `DB_*` settings for a single `DB_CONNECTION=mysql` line. Next time you migrate, Laravel will create the needed database file for you. No authentication needed!

Remember that reading and taking your time to understand the error messages (even the boring parts!) will usually let you know exactly what is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

A colleague of mine had the same error. What worked for him was setting "root" as password for the db in the .env file.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work in my case.